# Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]

Tags: python, apache2, pythonpath

I am trying to host and application myproject at VPS, Ubuntu-16.04 with Apache2. I have configure apache2 but its showing an strange error related to python. in apache2 error long. This is my 000-default.conf file content.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    Alias /static /home/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>



     WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
     WSGIProcessGroup myproject
     WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And this is the error log of apache2 error log ..

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I have also created an virtualenv at "/home/myproject/myvirtualenv", how could i solve this problem..